# In Makefile how do I build seperate executable for each C file

Tags: c, makefile

I am using Check for my C unit tests. For each C library file I create there should be one test file which should generate a single executable that is linked from the test and the source code. This executable should then be run to make sure all tests pass.

When there is only 1 test file and 1 source file everything works great. As soon as I add a second source file with the corresponding test file, it tries to link them all into 1 executable.

How do I get the second rule to pull 1 TEST_SRC and the matching SRC and header file into a TEST_OBJ then compile the 2 object files into an executable? Below is my current Makefile

```
OUT_DIR=bin
BUILD_DIR=build
TEST_BUILD_DIR=test_build
SRC_DIR=src
TEST_SRC_DIR=tests
SRC= $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
TEST_SRC= $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/%_tests.c, $(SRC))
TEST_OBJ= $(patsubst $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(TEST_SRC))
OBJ= $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

$(OUT_DIR)/string_calculator_tests: $(TEST_OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`

$(TEST_OBJ): $(TEST_SRC) $(SRC)
    gcc -c -o $@ $^ `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into assigning different targets and cascading them in the default one. E.g. `make testpkg1` or `make testpkg2` builds them individually, but `make all` simply calls `make testpkg1 testpkg2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly how you want this makefile to behave, but we can take it in stages.

Look at this rule:

```
$(TEST_OBJ): $(TEST_SRC) $(SRC)
    gcc -c -o $@ $^ `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`
```

*Each* object is built out of *all* source files. And you don't seem to have a rule for `OBJ`. So let's replace this with two static pattern rules:

```
$(TEST_OBJ): $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/%.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`

$(OBJ): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`
```

Then a rule to build an executable from a pair of object files:

```
TESTS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%_test, $(SRC))

$(TESTS): $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%_test : $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%_tests.o
    gcc -o $@ $^ `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`
```

Then a rule to build all tests:

```
.PHONY: all_tests

all_tests: $(TESTS)
```

That should be enough to get you started. Once this works, there are many possible improvements, such as targets to *run* the tests, and tidier ways to write the tests using advanced techniques like `vpath`. And we haven't even talked about header files and dependency handling...